# networkManager for NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsurlconnection

All,

I have created an app with several ViewControllers. In the viewController, I get data from a webserver using NSURLConnection. Now, in every ViewController, I post the data with:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.data.com/GetAllRequestsToPlay.php"]]];

NSString *post       = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PI=%i",self.ownPlayer.playerID.intValue];
NSData   *postData   = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and in every viewController I have the following methods:

- -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
- -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
- -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

this is all redundant because the code in these methods is in every viewController the same.

So I want to create a model class "connectionManager" which is used in every viewController to do all the networking (sending the post and handle respons).

Questions I have:

- Is there a tutorial or example code how to create this?
- how do I make it possible that the respons is caught in the connectionManager (so the "connection" methods)
- how can I notify the correct viewController that data is received and the the ViewController must do something with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a NSObject class which only deals with your NSURLConnections. In this class include all the required delegates and add a NSNotification to alert other classes when the data has been received.

Then instantiate this class in every ViewController where it's needed and listen for the NSNotification to process the received data.